# Encrypt the ROR Byte Data in JavaScript JSON array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, encryption, utf-8

I am using RoR for server side and sending some encryption data to JS Client side. For ROR I am using OpenSSl encryption technique.

```
`c= OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
 c = cipher.encrypt
 c.key = Digest::SHA256.digest(key)
 Base64.strict_encode64(c.update(value.to_s) + c.final)
`
```

This is my code for encryption in ROR

```
`var cipherParams:any = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
    ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted_data)
 });
var digest = CryptoJS.SHA256(key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
let bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherParams, digest, {iv: iv});
bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
`
```

This is my JS decryption logic

when I am encrypting some key value pair data from server I am not able to decrypt it. I am getting this error

> MalFormed Utf8

but when I am trying to decrypt single value like: **"5678"** I am getting correct value.If I changed **CryptoJS.enc.Utf8** to **CryptoJS.enc.Latin1** I am getting some unreadable value but error is not showing.

I think converting it to UTF8 is giving problem.But why?

I have tried many solutions. I am using proper key and digest and IV, I have checked it multiple times, and I am also sending proper string keys and values.

Comment: You can't encode binary data as UTF8 and expect to get the same back again when you decode it.  Doesn't work like that.  Use base64 instead.

Comment: It makes debugging more difficult to combine functions such as Base64 and encryption: `Base64.strict_encode64(c.update(value.to_s) + c.final)`. Just use multiple statements and intermediate variables., they you can print and see that is happening. It can also reduce errors.

Comment: @LukePark I have tried using Base64 instead of Utf8 but i am still getting encrypted data only. can you  tell me exact what I have to use.